# If a call may expire OTM, why won't a \$1 increase in the underlying's price necessarily increase the call's price by \$1?

Tags: asset-pricing

Zvi Bodie, Alex Kane, Alan J. Marcus. [*Investments* (2018 11 edn)](https://www.amazon.ca/Investments-Zvi-Bodie/dp/1259277178/ref=dp_ob_title_bk). [p 723 scanned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ocEM.jpg).

> Figure 21.9 verifies that the slope of the call option valuation function is less than 1.0,
>   approaching 1.0 only as the stock price becomes much greater than the exercise price. This
>   tells us that option values change less than one-for-one with changes in stock prices. Why
>   should this be? Suppose an option is so far in the money that you are absolutely certain it
>   will be exercised. In that case, every dollar increase in the stock price would increase the
>   option value by \$1. But if there is a reasonable chance the call option will expire out of the
>   money, even after a moderate stock price gain, **a \$1 increase in the stock price will not necessarily
>   increase the ultimate payoff to the call; therefore, the call price will not respond
>   by a full dollar**.

Pls elaborate the embolding? The authors didn't spell out all the reasons. If a call has a chance of expiring OTM

1. why won't a \$1 increase in the underlying asset's price "necessarily increase the ultimate payoff to the call"?
2. why won't the call price increase by a full $1?

Answer (score 2):

The reason that a call option price does not increase one-to-one with spot price of the underlying stock is simple: A 1 dollar increase in stock price only increases the *likelihood* that the option will be ITM. It is *not* a guarantee of 1 dollar increase in payoff at maturity. Naturally the price of call does not increase by 1 dollar.

More precisely, the price of the call should increase by the *probability* that the option will be ITM, which is less than 1. This fact is model-independent. (Try buying calls at one dollar plus current price whenever the underlying increases by one dollar, and see what happens.)

Accordingly, *any* model of option prices will have this property. Consider, for example, two basic models---the binomial tree and the Black-Scholes model.

**Binomial tree**

Suppose the stock price today is $S$. Tomorrow the stock price can be $S+\Delta S$ with probability $q$ and $S-\Delta S$ with probability $1-q$.

The price $C$ of a European call option with strike $K > S - \Delta S$ is therefore equal to the expected payoff $(S + \Delta S - K)q$.

(To be correct, assuming risk-free rate $r$, $q$ should be the risk-neutral probability given by 
$$
q e^{-r} (S + \Delta S) + (1- q) e^{-r} (S - \Delta S) = S.
$$
But this is not central to the discussion. 
)

If $S$ increases to $S + 1$, the price of the call becomes
$C = (S + 1 + \Delta S - K)q$.
The increase in the price of the call is exactly the probability $q$ of the call being ITM.

**Black-Scholes**

In the context of the Black-Scholes, 
the sensitivity of option price with respect to the underlying is called the *delta* of the option. It is a standard quantity that arises in *delta hedging*.

Let $C(S_0, K)$ denote the Black-Scholes formula for price of European call with strike $K$ maturing at time $T$.
The delta of the call is the partial derivative $\frac{\partial C}{\partial S_0}$. The delta is the increase in $C(S_0, K)$ when $S_0$ increases by 1 dollar.

As you would expect, it's immediate from the Black-Scholes formula that the delta $\frac{\partial C}{\partial S_0}$ is equal to the (risk-neutral) probability that the option will be ITM at maturity.

(In Black-Scholes, under risk-neutral dynamics, the price of the stock $S_T$ at maturity $T$ is given by
$$
S_0 e^{( r + \frac12 \sigma^2 )T + \sigma \sqrt{T} N} 
$$
where $N$ is a standard normal random variable. 
So $\frac{\partial C}{\partial S_0}$ is equal to 
$$
P( S_0 e^{( r + \frac12 \sigma^2 )T + \sigma \sqrt{T} N} > K)
$$
where $N$ is a standard normal random variable. 
)

Comment: Actually, the statement "...any model of option prices will have this property" should be any "any model where asset prices follow Markov processes will have this property". This is a technical point. All the basic models of option pricing are Markovian.

Comment: Thanks. "Try buying calls at one dollar plus current price whenever the underlying increases by one dollar, and see what happens." What's supposed to happen? I don't want to do this and lose money! It's smarter to place a limit order below the ask price.

Comment: @RhandalAllen In the long run, you will lose money (there is regardless of microstructure issues such as whether to use limit order/market order at bid/ask, etc) because, as the answer already explains, you would be overpaying for the option.

Answer (score 1):

If the strike of the call is \$20, a call option at expiry will be worthless for any stock price less than \$20. So there is no increase in value if the price at expiry is \$15 instead of \$14.

Ahead of expiry, this translates to the delta of the option being less than one, which implies that the call option value increases less than the rise in price.